# How to pipe python socket to a stdin/stdout

Tags: python, sockets, pipe

I need to write an app to contact to a server. After sending a few messages it should allow the user to interact with the server by sending command and receive result.

How should I pipe my current socket so that the user can interact with the server without the need of reading input and writing output from/to stdin/stdout ?

Answer (score 2):

You mean like using netcat?

```
cat initial_command_file - | nc host:port
```

the answer is, *something* needs to read and write. In the sample shell script above, `cat` reads from two sources in sequence, and writes to a single pipe; `nc` reads from that pipe and writes to a socket, but also reads from the socket and writes to its `stdout`.

So there will *always* be some reading and writing going on ... however, you can structure your code so that doesn't intrude into the comms logic.

For example, you use [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to create an input iterator that behaves similarly to `cat`, so your TCP-facing code can take a single input iterable:

```
def netcat(input, output, remote):
    """trivial example for 1:1 request-response protocol"""
    for request in input:
        remote.write(request)
        response = remote.read()
        output.write(response)

handshake = ['connect', 'initial', 'handshake', 'stuff']
cat = itertools.chain(handshake, sys.stdin)

server = ('localhost', 9000)
netcat(cat, sys.stdout, socket.create_connection(server))
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want something like [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html). Basically you'd create a `spawn` object that initates the connection (e.g. via `ssh`) then use that object's `expect()` and `sendline()` methods to issue the commands you want to send at the prompts. Then you can use the `interact()` method to turn control over to the user.